# How to set total space of footnotes?

Tags: spacing, footnotes, geometry

*How can be set the size of the footnotespace?*

I'm trying to get a visually constant body text, i.e. the main text should always look the same block. In order to do that, I'm leaving a large amout of space below the main text (60mm on a lettersize paper) to produce any footnote, mainly bibliographic references and short comments. Is there any way to specify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something more or less like this, basically tell latex to leave a big space (4cm here) but then tell it that footnotes do not take up any space so tex does not make the page any shorter when there are footnotes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\a{One two three four five six seven eight. }
\def\b{Red blue yellow green black white}
\def\c{\a\a\b\b\a\a\a\a}
\def\d{\c\c\c\a\b\c\c\c}

\addtolength{\footskip}{4cm}
%\addtolength{\textheight}{-4cm}
\skip\footins0pt
\count\footins0
\dimen\footins4cm
\let\oldfootnoterule\footnoterule
\def\footnoterule{\smallskip\oldfootnoterule}

\begin{document}


\b\a\d\d

!!!\footnote{something blah}
\b
!!!\footnote{another one}%
\footnote{a  long one: \b}
\d\d\b

!!!!!!\footnote{\itshape\d}
\b\b\d\a\b\d\d\d

\end{document}
```